# Restore status bar state after closing second UIWindow

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

There is main `UIWindow` that holds `MainViewController` which uses `lightContent` as `preferredStatusBarStyle`. I've created second `UIWindow` instance to show `PopupViewController`, which uses `default` as `preferredStatusBarStyle`.

When I show second `UIWindow` with `PopupViewController` status bar style changes to `default`, but when I hide it style does not changes back to `lightContent`.

The same problem applies to situation when I have VC with hidden status bar in popup window - status bar does not shows when popup window is dismissed.

New `UIWindow` creation:

```
// Prepare window to show dialog box in
newWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
newWindow?.windowLevel = 3

// Overlay new window
newWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
self.mainWindow.windowLevel = 1
self.mainWindow.endEditing(true)
newWindow?.isHidden = false

// Display dialog
newWindow?.rootViewController = PopupViewController()
```

New `UIWindow` dismissal:

```
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 1.0,
    delay: 0,
    usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
    initialSpringVelocity: 0,
    options: .curveEaseOut,
    animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.newWindow?.alpha = 0
    },
    completion: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.newWindow?.windowLevel = 0
        self?.newWindow?.rootViewController = nil
        self?.newWindow?.alpha = 1
        self?.mainWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
)
```

Thank you!

**EDIT**: Popup can appear at any time, I don't know which VC was active at that moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing I was looking for was `UIViewController.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`. It is convenient method to tell VC that status bar appearance was changed and needs to be restored.

```
// make main window key but transparent
self.mainWindow.alpha = 0
self.newWindow?.windowLevel = 0
self.newWindow?.alpha = 1
self.mainWindow.makeKey()

// restore status bar appearance  
self.mainWindow.rootViewController!.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

// Fade in main window with (status bar is in proper state at this moment)
UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.9,
        delay: 0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
        initialSpringVelocity: 0,
        options: .curveEaseIn,
        animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.mainWindow.alpha = 1
        },
        completion: { [weak self] _ in
            // destroy popup VC
            self?.newWindow?.rootViewController = nil
        }
)
```

[Here is useful article on this subject](http://tobiashelmri.ch/swift,/ios/2016/12/08/hiding-the-status-bar-smoothly-in-ios-10.html)

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

change the statusbar style on ViewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
}
```

Comment: Popup can appear on a random VC. It feels kind of hacky to me to set style back manually. I thought there is some way to tell "OK, now this window is master again, here is it's rootVC, inherit status bar settings from it".

Comment: did you set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO on info.plist

Comment: No, unfortunately I need it VC-based

Comment: then the only option is you have to manually change this in every VC

Answer (score 0):

1. Please add the following code on your first controller in which you change status bar color Light.

   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) { UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent, animated: false) }
2. Now in second Controller in which you want default status bar style, put the code :

   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) { UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.default, animated: false) }

You will definitely get the proper solution by above code

Comment: Problem is that popup can appear at any time and I don't now which VC was active at that moment

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for your case

1. New UIWindow creation:

   ```
    // Prepare window to show dialog box in
    newWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    newWindow?.windowLevel = 3

    // Overlay new window
    newWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.mainWindow.windowLevel = 1
    self.mainWindow.endEditing(true)
    newWindow?.isHidden = false

    // Display dialog
    newWindow?.rootViewController = PopupViewController()
    // Now you can change status bar style default or other style
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
   ```
2. New UIWindow dismissal:

   ```
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 1.0,
        delay: 0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
        initialSpringVelocity: 0,
        options: .curveEaseOut,
        animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.newWindow?.alpha = 0
            // Revert back to default
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        },
        completion: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.newWindow?.windowLevel = 0
            self?.newWindow?.rootViewController = nil
            self?.newWindow?.alpha = 1
            self?.mainWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    )
   ```

Comment: It's nice because unlike other suggested solutions this one handles everything right in popup VC, but looks like `UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle()` is deprecated since 9.0

Comment: @Andrejs Mironovs `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent`       I have already working in iOS 10 this code is working fine please check it.